# how can i create horizontal menu using kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

how can i create horizontal menu using kivymd

I want to create a list of items. Inside each item there is a button that shows a horizontal list to edit or delete the item .
I tried using MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial but I can't make the list horizontal.

And I tried with MDDropdownMenu and I couldn't make it landscape.

I  thinking of creating a FloatLayout in a position outside the screen and when pressing the menu button the position changes to the position of the menu button .

But I think it's a bad idea .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To create a horizontal menu using KivyMD, you can use the MDBottomAppBar component along with the MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial.

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp


KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Horizontal Menu'
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        elevation: 10

    MDBottomAppBar:
        anchor: 'right'
        reveal: True
        elevation: 10

        MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
            data: app.speed_dial_data
            rotation_root_button: False
            callback: app.callback
'''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    speed_dial_data = {
        'edit': 'square-edit-outline',
        'delete': 'trash-can-outline',
    }

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('your_kv_file.kv')

    def callback(self, button):
        print(button.icon)


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example doesn't work for me. What is your kivymd version?

Comment: I am getting this error `` AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'width' ``

Comment: The current version that I’m using is kyvimd-0.104.2

Comment: ^ Updated the code without testing it, try it again.

Comment: I changed the kivymd version, the example works now, but the button doesn't show up for me